# Spring boot 1.4.1 to 1.4.2 upgrade

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-boot

I tried to upgrade a Spring Boot project from 1.4.1 to 1.4.2.

Running from the IDE, the 1.4.2 project runs fine. But if I generate a war file and try to run from the command line, it breaks. If I downgrade to 1.4.1, it works ok again... Any Spring gurus out can enlighten me?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emfIntranet' defined in class path resource [com/ultraip/boot/IntranetPersistence.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributor: Error reading configuration file
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributor: Error reading configuration file
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributor: Error reading configuration file
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.parse(ServiceLoader.java:309) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$200(ServiceLoader.java:185) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:324) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:356) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52) [groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154) [groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:158) [groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at com.ultraip.boot.IntranetPersistence$_entityManagerFactory_closure4.doCall(IntranetPersistence.groovy:81) ~[classes!/:2.0-RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.with(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:242) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$757.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56) [groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) [groovy-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]
    at com.ultraip.boot.IntranetPersistence.entityManagerFactory(IntranetPersistence.groovy:76) ~[classes!/:2.0-RELEASE]
    at com.ultraip.boot.IntranetPersistence$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92cc0457.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$6(<generated>) ~[classes!/:2.0-RELEASE]
    at com.ultraip.boot.IntranetPersistence$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92cc0457$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8b256e0c.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:2.0-RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.ultraip.boot.IntranetPersistence$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92cc0457.entityManagerFactory(<generated>) ~[classes!/:2.0-RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry !/META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributor not found in /tmp/jar_cache7051424370993539398.tmp
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:150) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.parse(ServiceLoader.java:304) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    ... 112 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ultraip</groupId>
    <artifactId>ultraip-intranet</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-RELEASE</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <zk-version>8.0.2.2</zk-version>
        <zkspring-version>3.2.0</zkspring-version>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.1.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <spock.version>1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-3</spock.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.0.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.ultraip.boot.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mavensync.zkoss.org</id>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring ***************************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ZK ***************************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkplus</artifactId>
            <version>${zk-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkbind</artifactId>
            <version>${zk-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkspring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${zkspring-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Databases ***************************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Tools ***************************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.legrange</groupId>
            <artifactId>mikrotik</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Webjars ***************************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker</artifactId>
            <version>4.17.43</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- dependencia de eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker, forcando nesta versao -->
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>moment</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- dependencia de eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker, forcando nesta versao -->
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>moment-timezone</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-notify</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>animate.css</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-treeview</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>tablesorter</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- marcelustrojahn.com  ************************************************************* -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.marcelustrojahn</groupId>
            <artifactId>fiberhome-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test ***************************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<!--
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2-01</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9.2-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                    &lt;!&ndash; for 2.8.0-01 and later you must have an explicit dependency on groovy-eclipse-batch &ndash;&gt;
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.3-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
-->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addSources</goal>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testGenerateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            <goal>removeStubs</goal>
                            <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: How are you generating the war file? Have you followed the instructions in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging ?

Comment: mvn package... and the build section of my pom file is posted above. It's worth mentioning that the above works for 1.4.1, the war file is created the same way.

Comment: Can you post the complete pom.xml?

Comment: I updated above and I also tried both build sections. The second on (not commented) is the one Spring Initializr would create... It doesn't work too.

Comment: Can you try adding the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency with `provided` scope according to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging ?

Comment: That would be if I was going to deploy to a Tomcat server, which is not the case... It's run with "java -jar myapp.war". Tomcat is supposed to be embbeded on this application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128818/discussion-between-cjungel-and-m-trojahn).

Comment: Making it provided will still embed it into your war but in a different directory.

Comment: ok, I tested with provided, same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a regression in Tomcat 8.5.6. Your best bet is to downgrade to 8.5.5 by adding the following to the `<properties>` section of your pom:

```
<tomcat.version>8.5.5</tomcat.version>
```

See [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7360) for further details.

Comment: Yep. That fixed it. Thanks.